# use form variable in access report (DoCmd.OpenReport)

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass a variable (part of the sql where clause) to populate a report. No error, but report seems to be ignoring my variables value.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "report111", acViewPreview, , "[a].[fname] = 'oasgjasgip'"
```

I **should get 0 zero results** back, but i still get 3 rows.

```
id fname lname
--------------
1 mike lee
2 jon  thomas
3 bob  newman
```

Here is my query behind the report:

```
select distinct a.fname,b.lname from table1 a left join table2 b on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Is table1 or table2 a query in real life? And where does the form come in?

Comment: Forms are referenced as: Forms!Formname!ControlName  Your looks more like a table reference

Comment: What version of Access are you using? I tried your example with 2007 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're refering to a field with a table alias. The report is not going to be aware of that.

Try:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "report111", acViewPreview, , "[fname] = 'oasgjasgip'"
```

Or replace [a] with the actual name of the table especially if [fname] appears more than once.

Comment: In the query shown, table1 is aliased as a, so replacing [a] with [table1] will not work.